# Type of return value conditional on type of function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a type-safe JSON:API specification parser: The API response can either contain a single object or an array of objects (https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure).

E.g.: `GET /article`

```
{ 
  data: {
    type: 'article',
    id: article_id_1,
    attributes: { 
      name: article_1,
      price: price_1
    }
  }
}
```

or `GET /articles`

```
{ 
  data: [{
    type: 'article',
    id: article_id_1,
    attributes: { 
      name: article_1,
      price: price_1
    },
  }, {
    type: 'article',
    id: article_id_2,
    attributes: { 
      name: article_2,
      price: price_2
    },
  }]
}
```

I want the result of my function to be type-safe, so I want to create a generic function `parseData<T>` where `T` describes the type of the expected data. In this case:

```
interface TArticle {
   id: string,
   type: string,
   name: string,
   price: number,
}
```

What I have tried:

```
function parseData<T>(data: Data<T>): T | T[]
```

This works pretty well, except that the return type can still be either T or T[].
So when calling the function:

```
const result = parseData<TArticle>(articleData);
```

I (and TypeScript) don't know if result is TArticle or TArticle[].

I'm aware I can cast the result based on my knowledge of the API and what result I am expecting, but I would really prefer a proper TS solution for this.

Comment: The safest way would be to just add a typecheck: `if (Array.isArray(result)) { ...`

Comment: Why do you need `T | T[]`? Why not just `parseData<TArticle>` or `parseData<TArticle[]>`?

Answer (score 1):

You *don't need* to return `T | T[]`. You're in control of what you want to return (the type of the return, not at runtime) when you do this:

```
function parseData<T>(data: Data<T>): T {
```

So if you want a single `TArticle`, you just use

```
const result = parseData<TArticle>(articleData);
//    ^? TArticle
```

and if you want an array, use

```
const result = parseData<TArticle[]>(articleData);
//    ^? TArticle[]
```